# Way to set source port of TCP socket in node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, tcpsocket

I need to create TCP socket with specific source (local) port. For example, socket from my PC (192.168.1.2:7777) to server (192.168.1.3:7778). Why i see now is that node.js allows only random source port.
What is the way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to manually set the source port?

Comment: Some protocols that I implement in my software require predefined port on both sides of tcp connection